# An example to be a local martingale but not a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, local-martingales

What is a good example for $\varphi_{s}$, to $$\int_{0}^{t}\varphi_{s}dW_{s}$$ be a local martingale, but not a martingale?

A simplier question: what should I choose for $\varphi_{s}$, if I don't want $\int_{0}^{t}\varphi_{s}dW_{s}$ to be a martingale? Here $W$ denotes a Wiener process, and $\varphi$ a continuous process.

Comment: Hi the usual example of a strict local martingale is the inverse of the euclidian norm of a 3 dimensionnal Brownian motion starting at (0,0,1). The sde is straightforward to derive using Ito's lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take some random variable $Y$ which is not integrable (e.g. Cauchy distributed) and which is independent of $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Define $\varphi_s(\omega):=Y(\omega)$, then

$$\int_0^t \varphi_s \, dW_s = Y W_t$$

is a local martingale. However, it is not a true martingale since

$$\mathbb{E}(|Y \cdot W_t|) = \mathbb{E}(|Y|) \mathbb{E}(|W_t|)=\infty.$$

Comment: Hi saz, I have a few questions about this example. Why is $\phi_s$ is $L(W)$ ? It is $\mathcal{F}_0$ measurable so it predictible process ok, but for any stopping time (and so any sequence hof s.t. tending a.s. to $\infty$) I can't think of any s.t. $\tau$ for which the stopped process $ \int_0^{t \wedge \tau} \varphi_s \, dW_s$ is a true martingale regards

Comment: @TheBridge What is L(W)?

Comment: I meant $\varphi$ integrable with respect to $W$

Comment: @TheBridge What's wrong about taking $$\tau_n := \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $|Y(\omega)|>n$} \\ \infty, & \text{if $|Y(\omega)| \leq n$} \end{cases}$$ ? Then $\tau_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ (simply because $|Y|<\infty$ a.s.) and $\mathbb{E}\int_0^{t \wedge \tau_n} |Y(s)|^2 \, ds \leq n t < \infty$.

Comment: Is there also an example in which $\varphi_s$ is integrable? Or does this assumption already imply the martingale property of the $\int_0^t \varphi_s\Bbb dW_s$?

Comment: @saz I assume you take for $\mathcal F_0$ the completion of the sigma algebra generated by $Y$, is this correct?